# WorkFlow Foundation 4 WorkflowApplication Completed not triggered

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have the following code

```
AutoResetEvent instanceUnloaded = new AutoResetEvent(false);

WFStepsActivity workflow = WorkflowFactory.Current.BuildWorkflow(workflowinstance, requestinstance.RequestInstanceID);
WorkflowApplication wf = new WorkflowApplication(workflow);

wf.InstanceStore = WFInstanceStore.GetInstanceStore();

WFStepsPersistenceParticipant persist = new WFStepsPersistenceParticipant();
wf.Extensions.Add(persist);
wf.PersistableIdle = (arg) =>
{
    return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
};

wf.Unloaded = (arg) =>
{
    log.Info("WFName_" + wfsetting.Name + "_Unloaded and return.");
    instanceUnloaded.Set();
};
wf.OnUnhandledException = (arg) =>
{
    return UnhandledExceptionAction.Abort;
};

wf.Completed = (arg) =>
{
    if (arg.CompletionState == ActivityInstanceState.Closed)
    {
        persist.WorklflowCompleted = true;
    }
};

wf.Run();
instanceUnloaded.WaitOne();
return persist.WorklflowCompleted;
```

where the WFStepsActivity is just the Acitivity structure that we build from settings.
The workflow currently ends when a bookmark is created.

```
context.CreateBookmark(context.WorkflowInstanceId.ToString(), new System.Activities.BookmarkCallback(OnResumeBookmark));
```

The issue is after the bookmark is created the `wf.Completed` is never triggered.

Would like to check if the Complete is triggered if Bookmark is created.

As I know Complete event will be trigger if u Cancel, Terminate

Isn't it supposed that once the workflow stop of bookmarked, this event will be triggered?

Answer (score 3):

Bookmarks induce the workflow to become Idle, meaning that you must purposefully resume at the bookmark to continue and complete the workflow. First things first: [Grok bookmarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489442%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I'm not sure you have supplied enough code to allow anyone to properly diagnose the precise issue (I can't see your bookmark creation, nor your supporting classes etc).

It is also possible that your workflow is throwing an exception, the details of which are being swallowed. If you want to catch and log any unhandled exceptions I would ammend your code thusly:

```
Exception error = null;
wf.OnUnhandledException = (arg) =>
{
   error = arg.UnhandledException;
   return UnhandledExceptionAction.Abort;
};

// and then after you've waited for completion...
if (error != null) {
   throw error; // or handle it another way
}
```

Also useful: [Configuring Tracking for a Workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)